# npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall lstat npm ERR! path----- after entering------> npx express-generator --view=ejs myapp

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i was trying to create express application in VS CODE by using `"npx express-generator --view = ejs myapp"`. but getting error

```
npx express-generator --view=ejs myapp
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\aniru\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\aniru\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\aniru\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-18T13_47_40_949Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: please be sure to use backticks to format your code. Is `npx express-generator --view = ejs myapp` the command you are running? Typically there is no space between unix flags (`--view`) and the value you are passing them `ejs`. Did you try `npx express-generator --view=ejs myapp` instead?

Comment: try it on the command line (not in VSCode) and report what happens.

Comment: @JasonFB worked bro. Thank You very much!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try:
`npm run build` after:
`npm install` resulted in the same error for a completely new install, but
`npm update` worked, then subsequent `npm install`.

if you are using next `13.5.x` or newer use `npm run dev` to run

It worked for me, I hope it will help you!